# Why the actiondelete can’t be called?

Tags: php, yii

guys!

I am using rbac of yii1.1, when I called the actiondelete, I got a warning such as “You are not authorized to perform this action.”

My accessRule is:

```
 public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow only authenticated users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
        'actions'=>array('index','view'),
        'users'=>array('@'),

        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

And my actiondelete is:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{

    $model=$this->loadModel($id);   
    $project=$this->loadProject($model->project_id);
    $params=array('project'=>$project);

    if(!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('deleteIssue',$params))
    {
        throw new CHttpException(403,'You are not authorized to per-form this action');
    }

    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}
```

But, I can call the updateaction and viewaction exactly. Could you tell me why?

Comment: action delete is for user admin only while update and view are for all autenticated  users

Comment: You mention 'users'=>array('admin'), so it's allow for admin only. In update you mention @. Please check. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I rewrited the accessRule, and it has been solved.

array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','delete'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),